# Venn Diagram Based On Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So I have come up with a diagram that fits everything, except for the total number of people. I come up with a total of 97. Where am I going wrong?

78 people were surveyed about their coffee preferences.  6 people did not drink any coffee.  Of the 29 people willing to drink mild roast, 8 people only drink mild, 15 people drink mild and medium but not bold, and 6 drink mild and bold but not medium.  55 people were willing to drink medium roast and 28 were willing to drink bold roast.
[image: Here is my diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_{k,m,n}$ denote the number of people who like "mild $\iff k$, medium $\iff m$, bold $\iff n$":

- $A_{0,0,0}=6$
- $A_{0,0,1}=x$
- $A_{0,1,0}=y$
- $A_{0,1,1}=z$
- $A_{1,0,0}=8$
- $A_{1,1,0}=15$
- $A_{1,0,1}=6$
- $A_{1,1,1}=29-(8+15+6)=0$

We know that:

- $55=y+z+15+0$
- $28=x+z+6+0$
- $78=6+x+y+z+8+15+6+0$

Solving this system of $3$ equations in $3$ variables, we get:

- $x=3$
- $y=21$
- $z=19$

Hence:

- $A_{0,0,0}=6$
- $A_{0,0,1}=3$
- $A_{0,1,0}=21$
- $A_{0,1,1}=19$
- $A_{1,0,0}=8$
- $A_{1,1,0}=15$
- $A_{1,0,1}=6$
- $A_{1,1,1}=0$

Answer (score 1):

Well, you know from $8+15+6=29$ you know that nobody is willing to drink "medium, mild, and bold".  So put a zero in the center.

The 40 are not just "people who drink medium only".  They include people who drink "medium and bold but not mild".

Likewise the 22 also includes two areas, "bold only" and "medium and bold but not mild".

Now, work out how many are in the overlap.